# Make Media Controls Change Brightness

Tags: keyboard, brightness, remapping

On my external keyboard (Logitech K360), I have keys for volume and media control in the top row. I never use media controls, so I want to make them control my laptop's brightness. How could I unbind those keys from Pause/Play, Skip, Rewind, and bind them to brightness? I figure I just won't use the middle key (Play), and the left and right keys (Prev and Next) can be the brightness up and down keys.

The keypress events don't show with `xev`, though I can see them in `acpi_listen`. They are `CDPREV`, `CDPLAY`, and `CDNEXT`.

Edit: I'm on ubuntu 18.04.2

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89948/discussion-on-question-by-matt-f-make-media-controls-change-brightness).

Comment: Hello, does `sudo grep -rni 'CDPLAY' /etc/` return any output?

Comment: No, no output...